# Cambiar salida de texto en plugin WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Tengo un plugin en mi portal llamado `seriously-simple-podcasting` el cual me permite alojar y mover podcasts. La cosa es que la configuración de cada uno puedes indicar las URL de los feed en Spotify, Apple Podcast, etc. Cuando estos enlaces los muestra en la web, sale en modo texto así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría poder sustituir esta línea de texto por los logos oficiales. He encontrado en el plugin el código que genera esto:

```php
switch( $key ) {
                case 'stitcher_url':
                    $subscribe_display .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $data ) . '" target="_blank" title="' . apply_filters( 'ssp_subscribe_link_name_stitcher', __( 'Stitcher', 'seriously-simple-podcasting' ) ) . '" class="podcast-meta-itunes">' . apply_filters( 'ssp_subscribe_link_name_stitcher', __( 'Stitcher', 'seriously-simple-podcasting' ) ) . '</a>';
                break;
}
```

Haciendo pruebas para mostrar la imagen, he conseguido esto:

```php
case 'stitcher_url':
                    $subscribe_display .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $data ) . '" target="_blank" title="' . apply_filters( 'ssp_subscribe_link_name_stitcher', __( 'Stitcher', 'seriously-simple-podcasting' ) ) . '" class="podcast-meta-itunes"><img src="/uploads/Stitcher_Listen_Badge_Color_Dark_BG-e1556207428347.png"></a>' /*. apply_filters( 'ssp_subscribe_link_name_stitcher', __( 'Stitcher', 'seriously-simple-podcasting' ) ) . ''*/;
                break;
```

Pero creo que lo idóneo sería crear un filtro para sustituir el código fuera del plugin en si, ¿no? Con idea de que cuando el plugin se actualice de manera oficial, no tenga que estar volviendo a modificar el código.

Es en esta parte donde me pierdo, ya que no se como se aplica un filtro ni donde definirlo.

---------EDITO

He estado probando según leía ejemplos por internet, y he visto como crear un filtro y aplicarlo. Como en el plugin utiliza este filtro `ssp_include_podcast_subscribe_links` me he creado en mi fichero `functions.php` lo siguiente:

```php
add_filter( 'ssp_include_podcast_subscribe_links', 'cambiaLinks',1 );

function cambiaLinks(){
    $stitcherURL = '<a href="' . esc_url( $data ) . '" target="_blank" title="' . apply_filters( 'ssp_subscribe_link_name_stitcher', __( 'Stitcher', 'seriously-simple-podcasting' ) ) . '" class="podcast-meta-itunes">' . apply_filters( 'ssp_subscribe_link_name_stitcher', __( 'Stitcher', 'seriously-simple-podcasting' ) ) . '</a>';

    $stitcherURLOK = '<a href="' . esc_url( $data ) . '" target="_blank" title="' . apply_filters( 'ssp_subscribe_link_name_stitcher', __( 'Stitcher', 'seriously-simple-podcasting' ) ) . '" class="podcast-meta-itunes"><img src="/uploads/Stitcher_Listen_Badge_Color_Dark_BG-e1556207428347.png"></a>';

    $cambiaStitcherURL = str_replace($stitcherURL,$stitcherURLOK,$stitcherURL);

    return $cambiaStitcherURL;
}
```

Como digo, en el fichero del plugin `class-ssp-frontend.php` se utiliza el filtro así:

```php
if ( ! empty( $subscribe_display ) ) {
                $subscribe_display = '<p>' . __( 'Subscribe:', 'seriously-simple-podcasting' ) . ' ' . $subscribe_display . '</p>';
                $subscribe_display = apply_filters( 'ssp_include_podcast_subscribe_links', $subscribe_display );
                if ( $subscribe_display && ! empty( $subscribe_display ) ) {
                    $meta_display .= $subscribe_display;
                }
            }
```

Ahora no se me muestra nada, ni enlaces ni imágenes. Creo que es porque no utilizo bien la función de php `str_replace()`.

-----------2ª EDICION

He conseguido mostrar el logo correctamente, el problema es que la URL que le asigna es la de la página, no la del servicio en cuestión.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que aquí te sugiero no es la forma oficial, posiblemente alguien te de una mas correcta, pero esta es eficiente y rápida, además de perenne.

Lo que puedes hacer es modificar los enlaces que pone el plugin con jQuery o JS. Partiendo de la base de que no quieres que se borre con las actualizaciones, te sugiero que crees un tema hijo de tu tema actual, si no lo tienes hecho ya.

Después, agrega en el head.php de tu tema hijo un código como este:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Enlace itunes
enlace=$('a.podcast-meta-itunes'); //Selecciono el enlace por su clase, en este caso podcast-meta-itunes
enlace.text(''); //Borro el texto
enlace.append('<img src="/uploads/Stitcher_Listen_Badge_Color_Dark_BG-e1556207428347.png">'); //inserto la foto entre 
//las etiquetas <a></a>

//repetir código cambiando los enlaces que aparecen, seleccionandolos por su clase 

});
```

Esto debes hacerlo para cada enlace que quieras cambiar por fotografía. Es algo un poco mas sencillo que hacer un hijo de un plugin o tocar el `settings.php`. Si actualizas el plugin quizá cambien la clase de los enlaces, solo deberás cambiarlas también en este código. Si me pusieras el html donde están los enlaces y el orden, con sus clases, te podría hacer un script un poco mas preciso. Me cuentas que tal. Un saludo.

Comment: He intentado hacerlo mediante filtro, pero no consigo rescatar la URL correctamente del servicio en cuestión. ¿Podrías echarle un ojo al código editado de la pregunta?

Comment: Pues no conozco el plugin, así que no sabria muy bien que está haciendo ese código. Por ello, para mí no tiene mucha lógica lo que haces, porque no conozco el HTML ni el plugin que tienes, así que no puedo ayudarte por ahí. Solo el jQuery, que sé que no interferirá con nada que tengas ya puesto.